# Is this integral defined? $\int_0^0\frac 1x\:dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\displaystyle\int_0^0\frac 1x\:dx$
Is this integral defined? If it define, what is the value?

Comment: Riemann, Lebesgue or what other type of integral do you mean?

Comment: The function $f(x) = 1/x$ is defined everywhere except $x = 0$. Since the definition of a function at a finite number of points don't matter in integration (both Riemann and Lebesgue), it does not matter that $1/x$ is not defined at $x = 0$. What matters here is that the interval of integration is of length $0$ (also of measure $0$) and hence the integral is $0$ in both Riemann and Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Doesn't the fact that f blows up to infinity matter to Riemann? For the integral I define in my answer,any lower Riemann sum will be zero, but upper Riemann sums will not have well-defined values, and if we insisted, we would take it to be infinite..

Comment: @NoeBlassel: By definition, Riemann integral over interval of length $0$ is $0$. This fact has nothing to do with upper lower Riemann sums. These sums come into picture when interval of integration has finite positive length.

Comment: @NoeBlassel: We can however try to introduce Riemann sums for intervals of length $0$ also. In this case there will be only one partition of interval $[a,a]$ and upper, lower sum will be $0$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: again, I must insist this is only true for bounded functions. The Lebesgue criterion states equivalence between Riemann integrability of $f$ and i)boundedness of $f$, ii)zero measure of discontinuity points for $f$. In our case ii) is obviously true, but not so for i)

Comment: @NoeBlassel: function is obviously bounded on $[0,0]$. There is no issue on that front.

Comment: If $f$ were bounded on $[0,0]$, there would exist $M\in\mathbb{R_+}$ such that for all $x\in[0,0]$, $|f(x)|\leq M$. However, there is only one $x$ in $[0,0]$, $0$, but what $M$ is such that $|f(0)|\leq M$ ?

Comment: @NoeBlassel: I will write an my answer to avoid extended discussion in chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* defined, and has value $0$: write $I=\int_{0}^{0}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\chi_{\{0\}}dx}{x}$, where $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function on set A, $\chi_{A}(x)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $A$, and is $0$ otherwise. Now $\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, and outside of $\{0\},\frac{\chi_{\{0\}}}{x}=0$. Hence $I=\int_{-1}^{1}0=0$. Thus $I$ is defined, at least in the sense of Lebesgue.

Comment: I guess in the sense of Lebesgue theory, $\infty .0=0$ , i.e., value $\infty$ assumed in a set of measure $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I will take the case of Riemann Integral because the Lebesgue part is nicely done by Noe Blassel.

The definition of Riemann $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ has a pre-condition that $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$. This itself requires that $f$ must be defined for all points in $[a, b]$. However we are still able to talk about Riemann integrals like $\int_{0}^{1}\sin(1/x)\,dx$. How??

Note that Riemann integrals have a nice property that the value of integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ does not depend on values of $f$ on a finite number points in $[a, b]$. Thus we simply define the function $f(x) = \sin (1/x)$ at $x = 0$ in any arbitrary manner say $f(0) = k$ and the function remains bounded in interval $[0, 1]$ and since its only discontinuity is at $x = 0$ the function is Riemann integrable and the integral makes sense.

Next we come to the function $f(x) = 1/x$ on interval $[0, 0]$. Here $f$ is not defined on the interval under consideration. Hence it does not make sense to talk about its integral unless we define it on that interval. So we can define it in any manner by setting $f(0) = k$ and then $f$ is bounded on $[0, 0]$ and the integral is equal to $0$ (if we use upper/lower sums both are $0$).

Note that the argument of the previous case applies to any function on any interval of length $0$ and we expect the integral to be $0$ (via upper / lower sums approach). *Hence while studying Riemann integrals we add the following extra definitions*:

1) *If $f$ is any function then we define $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)\,dx = 0$.*

2) *If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ (with $a < b$) then we define the symbol $\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx$ as $-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$*

Together these two definitions help us to write the following theorem:

**Theorem**: *If $a, b, c$ are any points lying in some closed interval $I$ on which $f$ is Riemann integrable then $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx + \int_{b}^{c}f(x)\,dx = \int_{a}^{c}f(x)\,dx$$ irrespective of any order relations between $a, b, c$.*

Comment: How do we talk about integrals like $sin(1/x)$? This is not comparable, to $\int 0/0dx$ since above is bounded.

Comment: @gary: I have explained in my answer that such functions are easily handled by defining them at troublesome points in arbitrary manner.

Comment: I don't agree here, if I understood your argument. You can handle a product times a bounded expression, since the partition $x_{i+1}-x_i$ comprising a bounded value can be made indefinitely small, making that individual value in the Riemann sum zero. The problem is a different one when you have something like $ a\infty $, since , in Riemann integration ( unlike with the Lebesgue case) $ 0 \times \infty$ is not defined.

Comment: @gary: Riemann integration is only defined for bounded functions.

Comment: That is precisely why you can't integrate $1/x$ at $x=0$; that was precisely my point. Only way I see is just redefining $1/x$ to have a different value at $x=0$. But then you are not really integrating $1/x$.

Comment: @gary: the function $1/x$ is not defined at $0$. So if you want to talk about its integral then you need to define it. And in dealing with Riemann integration we can change the definition of a function at a finite number of points at our will.

Comment: I don't think we really redefine the value at a given point. We use the fact that the function is bounded together with the fact that we can make the partition width indefinitely small. But, yes,you are right it does depend on how we define $1/x$ at $x=0$. But then , in order to integrate it, as you said, we need to have an _a priori_ value at $x=0$, I would say, and not just one we choose I think the problem is ultimately, like you said, that we cannot integrate a function at a point where it is not defined.

Comment: And the issue becomes pathological because we do not have a context to allow us to "reasonably" define its value, context like an interval in which the function is defined. Anyway, I don't mean to be disrespectful, but we seem to be heading nowhere. I will let you have the last comment.

Comment: @Paramand Singh: I just think what you are saying is incorrect. You _do not_ redefine the value of a function. You use the fact that the function is bounded , say, by $M$, so that we can make $|M|(x_{k+1}-x_k|$ indefinitely small. But you cannot do this in Riemann integration when the function is unbounded. It is a different game. But, yes, this case of a function defined at a single point is not a simple one.

Comment: @gary: I think you are just trying to over complicate the matter. For definition of Riemann integral $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ it is necessary that $f$ be defined and bounded on $[a, b] $. And for any $f$ the integral is defined to be $0$ in case $a=b$. Also just to point out the function $1/x$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$ and hence unbounded on any interval which contains $(0,1)$. But a function defined on a degenerate interval consisting of only one point is always bounded. Your confusion perhaps arises because you are trying to think of $1/x$ as unbounded on $[0,0]$.

Comment: @Paramand Singh: Please don't talk about " My Confusion" , as I believe it is you who are confused. I have tried to be respectful to you, please don't condescend me just because I disagree with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63115/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-gary).

Comment: I am kind of running, please give me a few hours, sorry, got to go to work now.